Cron job does not run properly
I can not get my crontab to run a script that suspends my computer.
The script runs o.k. from a terminal.

~$ grep CRON /var/log/syslog
2024-09-22T05:15:01.538005-05:00 andy-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M CRON[23817]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null &&
debian-sa1 1 1)
2024-09-22T05:15:01.539793-05:00 andy-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M CRON[23818]: (andy) CMD (/home/andy/bin/Suspend.sh)
systemctl suspend



That's likely because suspending the system is inherently a privileged operation - see for example Hibernating from cron

@steeldriver Thanks a lot.

... tbh I would suggest looking into using a systemd realtime timer instead - there's some helpful material in this arch wiki
